# How to disable or change color for black rows while ListView scrolling

Tags: android, listview

Colleagues, please advice how can I or remove these black lines which appears on ListView scrolling (see screenshot) either disable them?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it dynamically use the method `.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled()`

Or, in your XML Layout you can use the tag `android:fadingEdge="none"` (credit to [nicky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182699/nicky))

Answer (score 2):

in android xml layout of scroll view

android:fadingEdge="none"

ad this

Answer (score 2):

Please don't just turn this off.  It is an important UI feature for the user to know there is more content above and/or below the list, and turning it off makes your UI behave inconsistently with the rest of the platform.

If you want to have a custom background color, the best way to do this is to make your own theme that sets it.  This way when a preview is needed to be shown of your app it will better match your actual UI, and the theme will automatically take care of using this color for things like fades.  Here is an example of what you could put in a res/values/styles.xml file, making such a theme which you can set for your application or an individual activity with `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    </style>
</code>
```

(Sorry about the syntax being a little odd -- it is because android:windowBackground currently can only be given a reference to a resource, not a constant color.)

For a list of the attributes you can use when declaring a theme, see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Theme